# VBA to only retrieve rows with 1 or more populated cells

Tags: excel, vba, summary

I have a code that retrieves data from those sheets that are not hidden to a summary sheet. Issue is that the other sheets contain both list drop down menus and some of them contain IF statements based on the input. But no "real" data populated into those cells if not specified.

The summary sheet is expected to only retrieve those rows with actual data specified in it. The sheets contain borders, so perhaps that could be an issue?

```
Sub CreateSummary()
    
    Const dName As String = "Summary"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    Const sColsAddress As String = "B:N"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    dws.Move After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    dws.UsedRange.Clear
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1 ' exclude 'dws' (last worksheet)
        Set sws = wb.Worksheets(i)
        If sws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            n = n + 1
            Set srg = Intersect(sws.UsedRange, sws.Columns(sColsAddress))
            If n > 1 Then ' all but the first worksheet; exclude headers
                Set srg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            Else ' first worksheet
                srg.Rows(1).Copy
                dfCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            End If
            srg.Copy dfCell
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(srg.Rows.Count)
        'Else ' worksheet is not visible; do nothing
        End If
    Next i

    Application.Goto Reference:=dws.Cells(1), Scroll:=True
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Summary created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This Excel function within a VBA code can determine if a row is empty or it has atleast 1 cell filled.

```
If WorksheetFunctions.CountA(sws.Rows(rownumber)) > 0 then 
   'This row has value in atleast a column
End If
```